# angular js on click and on blur

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to change the class on click and on blur depending on whether the input is entered or not. Below is my code.

```
  
      $scope.changeClassOnClick = function(event){
           $scope.class = "active";
    };
    
    $scope.changeClassOnBlur = function(event,username){
                  if(!username)
         $scope.class = "large";
     };
  
     .large{
    color:red
    }
     .active{
    color:blue
}
     <div class = "large" ng-class="class">
   <label class="label">Username</label>
            <input class="field" name="username" type="text" ng-model="username" 
            ng-click="changeClassOnClick()" ng-blur="changeClassOnBlur(username)"></div>
```

When something is entered i do not want the class to be changed.
Otherwise the class should change on click and on click away.
what is wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add ng-change="changeClassOnBlur(username)" also.

Comment: i did but isnt working as expected. :( I tried  ng-change="changeClassOnClick()" also, but is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what needs to be done. i need to refer to username by this. 
for e.g:
  if(this.username)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$scope.changeClassOnClick = function(){
    $scope.class = "active";
};

$scope.changeClassOnBlur = function(username){
    if(!username)
        $scope.class = "large";
};
```

```html
<div ng-class="class">
    <label class="label">Username</label>
    <input class="field" name="username" type="text" ng-model="username" ng-click="changeClassOnClick()" ng-blur="changeClassOnBlur(username)">
</div>
```

I've never come across an event parameter in an ng-click method.

Comment: i tried but does not work. I also tried  $scope.changeClassOnBlur = function(username){
    if(!$scope.username)
        $scope.class = "large";
};

Comment: Try removing the class="large" as well. because I think that is overriding the result you want.